# Database design - maintaining versions of an object

Tags: database, database-design, sql, relational-database

Suppose I've a `Person` object. This `Person` object in turn is having `name`, `address`, `accountNumber` and many other fields.

Now my requirement is that I want to maintain multiple version for each person in such a way that if I'm asked to give what's the state of any person at a given point in time, I can "re-construct"/"fetch" that state.

To give an example, let's consider that at time `t0` `address1` was associated with `personA`. And at `t1` (`t1` > `t0`), this person's address is changed to `address2`. Now I need to store both these information. My business need is that I can be asked what's the person's address at any point in time `t` where t can be:

- `t` < `t0` (in this case the address is not present)
- `t0` < `t` < `t1` (in this case the address is `address1`)
- `t` > `t1` (in this case the address is `address2`)

I want to model this in Database.

I don't want to use temporal tables because it's my business need and temporals are used for reporting and auditing purpose. (Or in worst case debugging an issue)

I want to keep things simple and because of that reason, I'm inserting the complete `Person` object into DB even in case of smallest change.

My `person` table looks something like this:

```
| person_id | name    | address        | phone_number | account_number | start | end |
| --------- + ------- + -------------- + ------------ + -------------- + ----- + --- | 
| 1         | personA | address text 1 | 123456789    | 741852963      | t0    | t1  |
| 1         | personA | address text 2 | 123456789    | 741852963      | t1    | -   |
```

Note that the `person_id` in this case is not unique in this table (and therefore it can't be a primary key in this table), because for a single person there can be multiple edits and so same `person_id` can repeate.

My business case is solved in a way that I can identify using `start` and `end` to check the validity of actual row for `person_id` 1.

The problem that I'm facing is I can use `person_id` as the reference key in other tables. Which I want to.

A unique auto-incremental column can be added (say `row_id`) that will uniquely determine every row in `person` table and that can be used as Primary key in this table and reference key in other tables. I don't want to do that since every other table will then have to refer to this table to see if any two `row_id`s are corresponding to the same `person_id` or not.

One solution that comes to my mind is that I can have a separate table `person_unique_ids` that will have a single column and will just store the unique ids of person. The `person` table will have the `person_id` which will be a reference to `person_unique_ids.person_id` and this way in my other tables also I can use this id without worrying about different ids for a single person being propogated in other tables.

But the above solution suggests to me that when inserting a new person, I should first insert an entry in `person_unique_ids` and get the newly inserted entry and use this to insert it in my main `person` table that will actually hold all the data.

This is leading to concurrency issues and I'm forced to synchronize the complete insert that's becoming a bottleneck for me.

Can anybody suggest an approach to this problem where I don't have a separate table, and still I'm able to solve all the historical data?

Note that in my actual use-case, I don't have person object. Rather its way too complex object. I've used `Person` just to mimic my use-case.

Comment: You mean something like a separate _history table_ combined with an object modelled in it's main table?

Comment: Yes.
But I don't need a separate history table. I need to maintain history of edits in my main table itself

Comment: Why don't you want a separate table?  If you [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design, this problem could be solved fairly easily

Comment: @DanPichelman Thanks for the suggestion, I tried doing that. Can you please elaborate? Please also note that I don't have just address that's changing, essentially anything related to person can change

Comment: On re-reading the comments, what's wrong with a history table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have correctly identified that this is a "problem" with relational data:
Modifying related entries is changing history - so to speak.

The question is: How to preserve identity?

Say you have a typical e-commerce scenario where you have

- a customer
- an order
- items of the order

So there has to be an *identity* preserved such that

`Martha Miller` issued `Order 12345` and ordered `123456789 Nike shoes`

And this *identity* has to be preserved,

- even when `Martha Miller` marries at a later point in time and is called `Martha Smith` from then on
- and moved from `New York` to `Los Angeles`
- and item `123456789` is now used for `Nike shirts` instead of `Nike shoes`.

One modelling strategy would be using multiple representations for the *identical* customer.

Say address with `id 1` is `Martha Miller` and address with `id 12345` is the same person, but now called `Martha Smith` and the customer is referenced via the same `address_customer_id` of say `af5aa5df-ad4b-42fa-97ed-e25e8cad1962` such that a `customer` can have several address entries. And everytime the adress is changed there will be a new entry in the adress table for the customer. And as long as the adress isn't changed the current one is used. And after a change the new one is used and the former  one is preserved. So for each point in time, there is exactly one identity of *this customer with this data did this order*.

The same goes btw. for the items.

Another strategy would simply be denormalization. Since it is historical data and you are only going to read it you will face none of the anomalies which to avoid you usually normalize your data.

Then there is the possibility of leveraging `JSON` as a datatype in most modern RDBMSses, which allows other fancy options like storing the whole order as a `document`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent [answer of Thomas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/402189/209774), I'd like to add that there are **native DBMS solutions** that support this need.

If your DBMS doesn't support temporal data, you may also be interested in having a closer look at the needs and making a distinction between managing of **time dependent data** and ensuring an **audit trail** of **historic data**.

### Native implementation techniques

Some RDBMS support natively fully time dependent data, almost exactly as you imagined.  In the SQL world, [ANSI SQL 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) introduced system versioned temporal tables:

- [SQL server 2016 support](https://www.sqlshack.com/track-history-data-changes-using-sql-server-2016-system-versioned-temporal-tables/) this feature.  In-depth information can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).
- Oracle supports it [since 12c](https://dbanotes.com/oracle-12c-temporal-database-f1fbdebffdf).  An more detailed introduction [here](https://www.salvis.com/blog/2014/01/04/multi-temporal-database-features-in-oracle-12c/).
- Other RDBMS engines support it as well, such as [MariaDB supports](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/temporal-data-tables/), and in the meantime some others.

### Time dependent data

Some data is known to be valid for a limited time.  We know that the value to be used depends on the relevant date.  Typical examples are a person's addresses or product prices.  There is in general a clear start date for a new value.

You may then:

- have a main entity for time independent data. The extreme case could be to have only the primary key (and may be the date of creation of the record).
- have a separate entity for time dependent data.  The key could be the primary key of the main entity and the start date. A nullable end date could be used to find easily the current value
- sometimes, a closer look allows to identify separate entities behind a group od data.  Typically,  the address could end up in a separate adress entity with a purpose (e.g. correspondence, delivery and invoice) and a period of validity of its own.

### Historic data

Historic data corresponds to a different need. This is for data that is assumed to be permanent, but can change for exceptional reasons.  We are therefore mostly interested in the current valid value. Only exceptionally are we interested in the historical value (e.g. for audit purpose, or for legal issues).

An example could be the date of birth.  In general it is not supposed to change. But a clerical error might result in this date being corrected at a later stage. If this date was used to give access to age based content (e.g. [PG13 games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_content_rating_system)), it could be useful to be able to trace back such changes in case of litigation.

This can be implemented as follows:

- The full user-accessible data is considered as time dependent (see solutions for 1).  THe queries are by default looking for the empty end-date.  The advantage is that you can easily browse through previous versions.
- The full data is considered as permanent without time dependency, but a separate table is used to archive the historical values in case these are needed.  It could be an ugly (but convenient) time dependent clone table. It could also be a lean (uggly but effective) change-log table,  with the name of the field, the old and new value, the date of the change and the user who made the change (a worldwide ERP market leader uses this technique to log changes to any critical field. It uses a change header to record the user and the date of change, and several related change items  with the table-name, field-name and the changed data)

Comment: Good explanation. In some cases user is allowed to insert time dependent data for the future (e.g. my surname *will* change in 2 months). In that case, if you want to query the current value, you can't just use `end_date IS NULL`, but rather `CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND IFNULL(end_date, '9999-01-01')`.

Comment: "Historic data" are in practice mostly just corrections of wrong input data which users fixes when he notices the mistake.

Comment: @user14967413 Interesting thought.  That may depend on the domain you're working on and I don't think that one can generalise this way.  There are plenty of historic data that are not related to error corrections but to the evolution in time of an entity.  The example of an address is very typical.  Very few people nowadays live from birth to death at the same address.  The size or the weight of a person can evolve all their lifetimes. Last names and even first names can change in many jurisdictions around the world.

Comment: @user14967413 indeed, a valid point for the future changes.  However,  recording evolution of historic data in the past is not completely identical to management of data in the future.  Take for example a purchase order.  At the time of the order confirmation, you may know a planned date of delivery.  But this is still uncertain.  The actual date will be known when it's delivered in the end.  And whenever there are planned futures,  a usual problem is to compare the planned and the actual date (or the planned vs.  actual amounts).

Comment: This requires to distinguish one or several versions of planned futures,  with actuals. So it'll really depend case by case how to deal with future.

Comment: Yes, many types of data are changed with the evolution of entity (address, surname). But I thought you have categorized this as "Time dependent data". "Historical data" on the other hand means exceptional changes, i.e. mostly errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150148/discussion-between-christophe-and-user14967413).

Comment: @user14967413 ok I see, you consider time dependent changes a separate category whereas I see it as a subcategory of historical data. Both point of views can be defended.